# Mobilefirst 8 Cordova plugin android build fail

Tags: android, cordova, ibm-mobilefirst

We create a simple cordova project

our platform info :

> cordova cli 6.5.0
>
> cordova android platform 6.1.2
>
> cordova ios platform 4.3.1

add these plugins:

```
cordova-plugin-mfp@8.0.2018112017
cordova-plugin-mfp-push@8.0.2018101607
```

execute cli : cordova build android

then got the build error message as shown below

> Total time: 3.451 secs Error:
>   /Users/DannyYang/Desktop/testCordova/test/platforms/android/gradlew:
>   Command failed with exit code 1 Error output: Failed to notify
>   ProjectEvaluationListener.afterEvaluate(), but primary configuration
>   failure takes precedence. java.lang.IllegalStateException:
>   buildToolsVersion is not specified.   at
>   com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:173)
>     at
>   com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.createAndroidTasks(BasePlugin.java:645)
>     at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin$10.call(BasePlugin.java:608)
>     at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin$10.call(BasePlugin.java:605)
>     at
>   com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:156)
>     at
>   com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:120)
>     at
>   com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.lambda$createTasks$1(BasePlugin.java:603)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$ActionInvocationHandler.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:93)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$ActionInvocationHandler.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:82)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.event.AbstractBroadcastDispatch.dispatch(AbstractBroadcastDispatch.java:44)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:79)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:30)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
>     at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy10.afterEvaluate(Unknown Source)     at
>   org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.notifyAfterEvaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:67)
>     at
>   org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.evaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:61)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.evaluate(AbstractProject.java:540)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.evaluate(AbstractProject.java:93)
>     at
>   org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configureHierarchy(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:42)
>     at
>   org.gradle.configuration.DefaultBuildConfigurer.configure(DefaultBuildConfigurer.java:35)
>     at
>   org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$2.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:124)
>     at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:22)    at
>   org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:91)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:53)
>     at
>   org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:121)
>     at
>   org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.access$200(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:32)
>     at
>   org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:98)
>     at
>   org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:92)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:91)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:63)
>     at
>   org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:92)
>     at
>   org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:83)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:99)
>     at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ExecuteBuildActionRunner.run(ExecuteBuildActionRunner.java:28)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:48)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:30)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:81)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:46)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:52)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:37)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
>     at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)    at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.health.DaemonHealthTracker.execute(DaemonHealthTracker.java:47)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:60)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:72)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.health.HintGCAfterBuild.execute(HintGCAfterBuild.java:41)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:237)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:54)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:40)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - Where: Build file '/Users/DannyYang/Desktop/testCordova/test/platforms/android/build.gradle'
>     line: 92
> - What went wrong: A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.
>
>   > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration 'classpath'.
>   >     Could not find com.google.android.gms:strict-version-matcher-plugin:1.1.0.
>   >      Searched in the following locations:
>   >          https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/strict-version-matcher-plugin/1.1.0/strict-version-matcher-plugin-1.1.0.pom
>   >          https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/strict-version-matcher-plugin/1.1.0/strict-version-matcher-plugin-1.1.0.jar
>   >          file:/Users/DannyYang/.m2/repository/com/google/android/gms/strict-version-matcher-plugin/1.1.0/strict-version-matcher-plugin-1.1.0.pom
>   >          file:/Users/DannyYang/.m2/repository/com/google/android/gms/strict-version-matcher-plugin/1.1.0/strict-version-matcher-plugin-1.1.0.jar
>   >      Required by:
>   >          unspecified:unspecified:unspecified > com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0

We check the offical doc [(link)](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/application-development/sdk/cordova/)

> cordova-ios: >= 4.1.1 and < 5.0
>
> cordova-android: >= 6.1.2 and <= 8.0
>
> Apache Cordova CLI(>=6.x and <9.0)

Our environment is in compliance with the prerequisites

But why did it fail to build?

> EDIT:
>
> full source code :
>
> https://github.com/DannyYang/MFP_plugin_test

Comment: Please update your cordova android platform to version 6.4.0. Also, please specify your gradle version.

Comment: Thanks!  Which gradle version that mfp plugin support?  By the way, which ios platform version that mfp plugin support?

Comment: gradle version 4.4, gradle plugin version 3.0.0, platform version 6.4.0 still build fail

Comment: Is it still failing with same error? Also, please share your config.xml file.

Comment: Full source code : https://github.com/DannyYang/MFP_plugin_test

Comment: Can you please remove the cordova-plugin-mfp-push and try to build the application?

Comment: Similar issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53058933/latest-cordova-plugin-mfp-push-errors-when-doing-cordova-build-android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve this problem of cordova-plugin-mfp-push plugin build failed,
just modify build.gradle

1. replace maven url to google()
2. dont use '+' by dependencies libs